# How to flatten an array to a string of the values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this.

```
'keyvals' => 
    array
      'key1' => 'value1'
      'key2' => 'value2'
      'key3' => 'value3'
```

Is there a cool way to flatten it to a string like `'value1 value2 value3'`? I also have access to PHP 5.3 if there's something new there.

Comment: That's not even correct syntax, can you provide a real example? And what exactly do you want to do? Do you want to print each value in a row, or do you want to define an array in one line?

Comment: @Griffin, I'm sorry, this syntax is out of var_dump()

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$someArray = array(
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => 'value2',
  'key3' => 'value3'
);
implode(' ', $someArray); // => "value1 value2 value3"
```

Answer (score 5):

See [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$flat = implode(' ', $array['keyvals']);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have to flatten this array to single-dimensional - take a look to this function (from Kohana fw)

```
/**
     * Convert a multi-dimensional array into a single-dimensional array.
     *
     *     $array = array('set' => array('one' => 'something'), 'two' => 'other');
     *
     *     // Flatten the array
     *     $array = Arr::flatten($array);
     *
     *     // The array will now be
     *     array('one' => 'something', 'two' => 'other');
     *
     * [!!] The keys of array values will be discarded.
     *
     * @param   array   array to flatten
     * @return  array
     * @since   3.0.6
     */
    function flatten($array)
    {
        $flat = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_array($value))
            {
                $flat += flatten($value);
            }
            else
            {
                $flat[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $flat;
    }
```

but if you just want to get a string - use native `implode()` function