# put ARRAY data into a variable

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, count

I have the following code...

```
for($i=0; $i<$totalquestions; $i++){
echo $_SESSION["responses"][$i]."-";
}
```

the data as an example would be the following:

```
$_SESSION["responses"][1] = '1';
$_SESSION["responses"][2] = '20';
$_SESSION["responses"][3] = '55';
$_SESSION["responses"][4] = '60';
```

I would like to put everything in a single variable, example  ...

```
$test = "1-20-55-60";
```

somebody could help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flatten an array to a string of the values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941629/how-to-flatten-an-array-to-a-string-of-the-values)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need much of a tweak. You need to start the loop at 1, not 0 (because of how you structured the session elements, and also you need a condition over when to add the `-` otherwise you get a spare one poking off the end where you don't want it.

```
$totalquestions = 4;
$_SESSION["responses"][1] = '1';
$_SESSION["responses"][2] = '20';
$_SESSION["responses"][3] = '55';
$_SESSION["responses"][4] = '60';
$test = "";

for($i=1; $i<=$totalquestions; $i++){
  $test .= ($i > 1 ? "-" : "").$_SESSION["responses"][$i];
}
echo $test;
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c20f8f390691074c1c5fbd621df396ac31fbeeb7

Comment: thanks for answering, what I need is to be able to have the codes "1" "20" "55" "60" inside the $ test to be able to use the variable $test in other lines

I would like it to be like this: 

`$test = "1-20-55-60";`

to then use it in other php lines for example:

`if ($test == '1-20-55-60')`

will it be possible?

Comment: So just replace the `echo` with `$test .=` then. If you want to assign it to a variable, assign it to a variable! That's a very standard procedure, it's not too complicated...

Comment: I updated the answer, just in case you are not sure of the basics of assigning values to variables

Comment: It worked perfect !! Thank you very much for your help. :'D

Comment: No problem. If the information helped you, please remember to mark the answer as "accepted" - thanks.